# Installing california calendar 0.4.0 on ubuntu 14.04 LTS

Tags: 14.04, gnome, calendar

First to mention, I am new to linux, so this might be a stupid question:

Is it possible to install [california 0.4](https://wiki.gnome.org/Apps/California) on ubuntu 14.04 LTS?

If yes, how?

I had installed Version 0.1.4, but I had problems syncing webdav calendars and repeatedly prompting keyring passwords. So I uninstalled california 0.1.4 and was hoping that version 0.4 is more stable.

I tried installing it both via `ppa:yorba/ppa` and `ppa:yorba/daily-builds`. The first gave "package not found", the second installed version 0.1.4. So I removed it again.

Thirdly I downloaded the tar file from the above link, and tried to `./configure` which gave me this error message:

```
no configure: error: Package requirements (
glib-2.0 >= 2.38.0
gobject-2.0 >= 2.38.0
gtk+-3.0 >= 3.12.2
gee-0.8 >= 0.10.5
libecal-1.2 >= 3.8.5
libsoup-2.4 >= 2.44
libgdata >= 0.14.0
goa-1.0 >= 3.8.3
gobject-introspection-1.0 >= 1.38.0
) were not met:

Requested 'gtk+-3.0 >= 3.12.2' but version of GTK+ is 3.10.8

Consider adjusting the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable if you
installed software in a non-standard prefix.

Alternatively, you may set the environment variables CALIFORNIA_CFLAGS
and CALIFORNIA_LIBS to avoid the need to call pkg-config.
See the pkg-config man page for more details.
```

How to add all these packages or adjusting the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable? I tried using synaptic, but I just don't know how to do it properly..

Or is Version 0.4.0 simply not available for Trusty Tahr? How can I tell other than daily builds of 0.4 ARE available in [launchpad](https://launchpad.net/~yorba/+archive/ubuntu/daily-builds) for 14.10 and 15.04 but NOT for 14.04? I mean the build for 14.04 hasn't been updated since almost a year. Isn't there going to be an 'easy to install' version 0.4 for the LTS-ubuntu 14.04?

Thanks for help.

Comment: California 0.4 requires GTK+ 3.12 or higher. Trusty has GTK+3.10. So you can **not** install that version in trusty. To install you must upgrade it to vivid. Daily build for 14.04 is not available because of that. And No, there is no `easy to install` for 14.04 because higher version california uses some feature which is only available in GTK+ library > =3.12. Getting 3.12 on trusty is not possible either because that would be same as recompiling whole 10,000+ packages in the repo!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

California 0.4 requires GTK+ **3.12** or higher. Trusty has GTK+3.10. **So you can not install that version in trusty.** To install you must upgrade it to **vivid**.

Daily build for 14.04 is not available because of that. And No, there is no `easy to install` for 14.04 because higher version california uses some feature which is only available in GTK+ library **> =3.12**. Getting **3.12** on **trusty** is not possible either because that would be same as recompiling whole 10,000+ packages in the repo!